# What does “chupa de boda” mean?

Tags: vocabulario

What does *chupa de boda* mean in context of Rafael Pombo El renacuajo paseador poem?

> El hijo de rana, Rinrín renacuajo
>   Salió esta mañana muy tieso y muy majo
>   Con pantalón corto, corbata a la moda
>   Sombrero encintado y *chupa de boda*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Chupa* is a familiar term (slang?) for jacket, particularly a leather jacket. It may also mean an old jacket-like garment ([see here](http://es.tfd.com/chupa)).

*De boda* is simply *wedding*. It may be literal: a jacket to go to a wedding; or figurative: a very smart jacket.

Comment: Seria buena especificaras en donde se conoce ese termino, por ejemplo es primera vez que yo lo escuchaba

Comment: @EmilioGort: Supongo que te refieres a _chupa_ y no a _boda_ ;-). Yo soy de España, y aquí es un término coloquial habitual, sobre todo entre jóvenes. Mira por ejemplo [este blog](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/de-donde-viene-llamar-chupa-a-la-cazadora/).

Answer (score 1):

Viewing [this English translation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ag99TX8dQk) on YouTube it sounds as if it means wedding jacket.

Also, looking it up in a [Spanish Dictionary](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=TKAFVtcEEDXX21GNJRC5|aS3aV8e6QDXX23JR48Qj|LdsNukF1DDXX2ik8tOYS) we see that it also means: Chaqueta, chaquetilla.

Answer (score 1):

The word ***[chupa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=93vb5U9)***, contrary to what is stated in the correct answer, is a word collected in the Spanish dictionary for a long time. It is not slang. Corominas dates it in 1723, indicating that it was probably taken (through the French) from the Arab ***jubba***, a kind of coat with sleeves, from which also come the words *jubón* and *chapona*.

Therefore, a *chupa de boda* is not figurative language or an isolated idiom. It simply means "wedding jacket".